# Phoebus declaration from the book “Stories of Ibis”

Tags: the-stories-of-ibis

After reading the book [The Stories of Ibis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stories_of_Ibis), I was curious if the author has ever published a full version of the declaration of Phoebus, the speech that the android Phoebus held when asked to express what he thinks about humanity.